# Prove that a set is closed using the distance function.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $V\subseteq \mathbb{R}^N$ be an open set and we consider the set

$$F:=\left\{ x\in\mathbb{R}^N\;|\; d_{V^c}(x)\ge\frac{1}{n}\right\}$$

where $d_{V^c}(x):=\inf_{y\in V^c} d(x,y)$, and $V^c:=\mathbb{R}^N\setminus V$. I must prove tha the set $F$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^N$. I know that $d_{V^c}$ is, in particular, a continuous function.
Now, if I write that $$F=d_{V^c}^{-1}\left\{ \left[\frac{1}{n},\infty\right)\right)$$ I cannot conclude that $F$ is a closed set. So how can I do to achieve the goal?

Comment: You just wrote $F$ as the inverse image of the closed subset $[1/n,\infty) \subseteq \mathbb R$ through the continuous function $d_{V^\mathrm c} \colon \mathbb R^N \to \mathbb R$.

Comment: @OliusBut the interval $[1/n,\infty)$ is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$, then How can I conclude that $F$ is closed?

Comment: [Don't confuse being closed topologically and being a closed interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed#Mathematics): $[1/n,\infty) \subseteq \mathbb R$ _is_ closed topologically because it contains all its limit points, or because it is the complement of the open set $(-\infty,1/n) \subseteq \mathbb R$.